How to add transient properties to a JPA query
I am using JPA with Spring Boot annotations.
I have a case where I want to do a query against a table that includes two additional computed columns that are not declared in the Entity class for that table. I thought I could do this by extending the Entity class and adding the two properties to the subclass. It compiles, but at runtime it complains that the subclass is an Unknown Entity. Adding the @Entity annotation to the subclass doesn't solve the problem.
This is not a Projection, in the sense that I still want all of the original fields of the Entity plus some new ones, rather than a subset of the original fields. I'm hoping there's a simple way to do this without having to create a new Repository.
Thanks,
Frank

You can have multiple @Entity classes with different attributes that target the same table. It should not be a problem

Can't you simply add the two additional fields to the class annotating them with @Transient or using the transient modifier? Or... as they are calculated fields, add them as methods or even getters...

if you already have a correctly declared entity, you could use a class that wraps around your entity:
public class PojoEntity{
   private EntityClass entityProp;
   private String columnExtra;
   private Double total;

   public PojoEntity(EntityClass entityProp String columnExtra, Integer total){
   this.entituProp = entityProp;
   this.columnExtra = columnExtra;
   this.total = total;
}
// Getters and Setters
}

In your Dao class you would have to call it this way:
public interface MyDao extends JpaRepository<EntityClass, ClassId>(){
    @Query("SELECT package.PojoEntity(ec, columnExtra, total) FROM EntityClass ec WHERE condicion1 AND condicion2...")
    PojoEntity query();
}

Of course, JPQL has its limitations and if you want to use a native query I suggest you use myBatis with your mappers, in addition to the JPA.
